# NSPredicate with format has to be reversed when two format strings are used

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nsstring, nspredicate

I have a `NSManagedObject` with the following attributes:

- status
- kind
- priority

Now I want to be able to filter my entity with these attributes respectively. So I would expect that I have to have a predicate along those lines:

```
status CONTAINS[c] ‘open’
```

I get really weird results, as soon as I have two variables in my predicate and I have to **reverse** the order of `kind` and `value` in my case so that I get the desired results:

```
NSString *kind = @"status"; // DEBUGGING
NSString *value = @"open"; // DEBUGGING

// This works although it defies all logic
NSString *predicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"('%@' CONTAINS[c] %@)", value, kind];
self.myFilterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate];
```

This however, does not work for some reason:

```
NSString *predicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ CONTAINS[c] ‘%@‘)”, kind, value];
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The first predicate string causes a crash. The second predicate does not compile because it contains typographical quotation marks instead of the simple ones. After fixing that, the second predicate string works and gives the expected results. - However, the proper way would be to use `self.myFilterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", kind, value];` .

Comment: @MartinR sorry for those characters. Can you tell me what `%K` does in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the exact problem, but generally you should not use `stringWithFormat` to create predicate. It causes problems as soon as the substituted key or value contain
any special characters like spaces or quotation marks.

A better way is

```
self.myFilterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", kind, value];
```

`%K` is a placeholder to be replaced by a *key path* such as "status".